# How do I connect a simple Java HTTP client app to a web resource using Ngrok?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, apache-httpclient-4.x, ngrok

I have written a simple Java HTTP Client App which should connect to an outside resource from my machine using `ngrok`. The sample code is:

```
public void sendMessage(String number, String message) {

    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                LINK);
        httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", getBasicAuth()));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LOGIN", LOGIN));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PASSWORD", PASSWORD));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message", "Hello, World!"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

The `ngrok` documentation tells I should provide a port to a local web server.
But in my case it is a simple single-class application with nothing like Tomcat configured. So how should I configure ngrok to transmit my app's HTTP requests then?

I have also tried running my application behind a Tomcat server, setting the correct port on both sides (tomcat and ngrok) - still no communication has been established.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you want, but you just plan to make a client request to a remote server, then you don't need *ngrok* to do that. Ngrok helps you to setup a web-server on your local host available to the outside world because by default firwalls do not allow connections from the internet to localhost.

From your code, I see that you're trying to send the request to a certain `LINK`. Have you tried pinging the LINK to see if it's actually accepting connections (alive)? Is your computer connected to the internet when you run the program?